# How to pass id to an action in the controller - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating reports with the axlsx gem and I need to pass the id of the event that I select to generate its report, but I do not know how to get that id in the action of my controller that I created.

I am created this table where I must obtain the id that I want to send to the action:

[My table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYZIb.png)

This is the code of my table, Here I try to pass the id, but I do not know how to get it in the controller:

```
def data
    events.map do |event|
      [
          event.name,
          (
              link_to(
                  raw("<button id='button' class='btn btn-default'><i class='fa fa-file-text' style='cursor: pointer;'></i></button>"),
                  assistants_report_admin_report_assistants_by_events_path(event.id, format: :xlsx)
              )
          )
      ]
    end
  end
```

The action on my controller:

```
def assistants_report
    @event_report = Event.where(id: "I need the id here!")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.xlsx {render xlsx: 'report_all_assistants', :filename => "aa.xlsx", layout: false, disposition: "attachment"}
    end
  end
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :report_assistants_by_events do
      collection do
        get "assistants_report"
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `member` instead of `collection` in your `routes.rb`, then in your controller, you can access id by `params[:id]`.

You also need to replace `assistants_report_admin_report_assistants_by_events_path` with your new path after changing from `collection` to `member`.